# Obtener el nombre de un componente a través de un evento c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo varios botones y todos tienen el mismo evento y al darle click sobre uno quiero obtener el nombre del boton al que le hago click, intento hacer algo como esto:

```
private void Boton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sender.name;
        }

private void Boton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.name;
        }
```

He intendado hacer algo como `sender.GetType().GetProperty("Name").Name` y otras cosas raras, pero no consigo obtenerlo que busco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el argumento sender.  es el Control (el botón en este caso) que ha provocado el evento click:

```
var button = sender as Button;
 button.Name ...
    ...
```